# TeamCity: Prevent 2 builds from running simultaneously

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-7.1

I don't want Build Config A and Build Config B to run at the same time. This is because they share the same resource which cannot be accessed simultaneously. However each build config is run by a separate agent so it is possible for them to run simultaneously.

Instead I would like one build config, when triggered, to wait for the other to finish if it is running. For example if Build Config B begins to run but Build Config A is already running, then B would wait until A finishes and then B would run.

I don't think a snapshot dependency will work because that assumes one config has a dependency on the other which is not true in my case.

Comment: why can't they run independently? would they interfere with each other via a shared resource? could you pin them to the same agent?

Comment: Will the builds always run together? If so, you could remove all build triggers from one of the builds and assign a Finish Build solution to it. This will queue build B after build A finishes. That said, I still like Matt's suggestion of forcing them to both run on the same build agent.

Comment: They can't run independently because of a shared resource. Ideally I would find a way around this but it will take some reconfiguring, so I'm hoping at least temporarily to prevent them from running simultaneously.

Comment: In that case, just make a rule on the agents tab, that they have to run on the agent name containing xxx ( whatever that is ) then those builds can only run on that agent and will never run at the same time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a quick and dirty, just make a rule on the compatible agents tab for the project. That they have to run on the agent name containing xxx ( whatever that is ) then those builds can only run on that agent and will never run at the same time.

Comment: I guess it would be nice if TeamCity just had an option against a build configuration i.e. `Enable simultaneous builds` which was on by default. Can't imagine it would be a difficult plugin to write, maybe I'll give it a go if I have time - however, in the meantime this workaround is more than acceptable :)

Answer (score 14):

Keith, there are two plugins that can help you:
The first one is [Groovy plugin](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TW/Groovy+plug). It has functionality of creating name locks over all projects.

The second one is [TeamCity.SharedResources](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TW/TeamCity+Shared+Resources). It has functionality of definig shared resources and locking them with read and write locks. However, resources defined in this plugin, are are defined per-project. We are actively developing this plugin, so you are welcome to watch its page in [our tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-3798)

Comment: Shared Resources is bundled with TeamCity as of v8.0 so that seems like the right answer now.

Answer (score 3):

In the newest version of TeamCity, you can configure this parameter. Go to the Edit Configuration Settings -> Edit Configuration Settings and set parametr:

*Limit the number of simultaneously running builds (0 — unlimited)*