# Is it possible to prevent concurrent builds across certain configurations?

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I have a TeamCity (8.0.5) setup running with multiple agents and multiple projects with multiple configurations.

We have some build configurations for CI (eg compile and unit tests) and some of the configurations used for automated deployment.

The deployment configurations run  scripts on shared services (eg IIS / sql etc) and so cannot be run in parallel with other deployment builds in any project.

Is there any way to limit this in team city?

I've have seen setting to "limit concurrent builds" but this only applies to a single configuration, I've also tried to limit the deployment builds to single common agent but I haven't been able to do this so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468161/teamcity-prevent-2-builds-from-running-simultaneously

Comment: It's a different question actually. Keith is on TC 7 and looking to limit builds within the same project.  My question relates to TC 8 and limiting builds in different projects

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TeamCity 8 shipped with the Shared Resources plugin built-in and supported. It allows you to create a Shared Resource on any project in the hierarchy and under Build Features of a Build Configuration you can define what Shared Resources need to be available for the build to run, otherwise it'll be queued until the resource is available and a lock can be taken.

For more information, take at look at the TeamCity documentation: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Shared+Resources

Comment: It sounds like the right thing however the docs say the resource is configured at the project level. My builds are in different projects?

Comment: I've just tried this out and you can add the shared resource into the <Root Project> and it gets inherited down so this does solve my problem

Comment: @Twisted yep, sorry I wasn't clearer what I meant by "any project in the hierarchy".